# Define a new caption in a listing environment

Tags: listings, captions

I want to have different listings with different types of captions, consider that I've got the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.98}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numberbychapter=true,    
    numbersep=5pt,        
    float=tp,     
    tabsize=2,     
    xleftmargin=5pt,
    framexleftmargin=5pt,
    extendedchars=true,         
    breaklines=true,
    frame=tb,   
    showspaces=false,       
    showtabs=false,        
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    rulecolor=\color[rgb]{0.78,0.78,0.78},
    framerule=0.5pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{1.0,0,0}  
}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
    {\noindent\minipage{\linewidth} 
            \lstset{#1}
    }
  {\endminipage} 

\lstnewenvironment{tip}[1][caption=Tip]%
    {
    \noindent\minipage{\linewidth} 
            \def\lstlistingautorefname{Tip}
            \lstset{#1,keywordstyle=\color{black},numberbychapter=false,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black}\bfseries, backgroundcolor=\color{white},frame=none,captionpos=bc }
    }
 {\endminipage}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}[caption=Test]
Code test..
\end{code}

....Look, just because I don't be givin' no man a foot massage don't make it right for Marsellus....

\begin{tip}
A tip!
\end{tip}

{\begin{figure}%
This is what I want!
\caption{}%
\label{}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following:

[image]

Basically I want all listings to have the caption in the Top Left, but for the environment `tip` I want it to be Bottom Center as it looks at the third example but the caption should say "Tip 1".

Is this possible? If So, How?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill, Ok! I'll do that and edit the question. Meanwhile if anyone know what I am talking about, be my guest and answer the questiot!

Comment: @PeterGrill, Updated, does it look better like that?

Comment: Does not compile for me. I get `! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language.'  You should also eliminate most of the settings `lstset` unless they are necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `caption` package offers the possibility to define and execute own option sets via `\captionsetup[<name>]{...}` and `\captionsetup{options=<name>}`. This way you can define different looks for the captions of `code` and `tip`.

(Unfortunately the key `options` is not documented well, currently it's only listed within the alphabetical reference of the `caption` package documentation.)

To get `tip` labeled and counted independently one needs to define an own counter for `tip`. This part of the solution was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900847/latex-listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.98}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}

\lstset{
% ...
    float=tp,     
% ...
}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[code]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
    {\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}%
            \lstset{#1}%
            \captionsetup{options=code}% execute options set with \captionsetup[code]{...}
    }
  {\endminipage} 

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tip}
\lstnewenvironment{tip}[1][]%
    {%
    \noindent\minipage{\linewidth}%
            \def\lstlistingname{Tip}%
            \def\lstlistingautorefname{Tip}%
            \let\c@lstlisting=\c@tip
            \let\thelstlisting=\thetip
            \lstset{#1,keywordstyle=\color{black},numberbychapter=false,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black}\bfseries, backgroundcolor=\color{white},frame=none,captionpos=bc}%
            \captionsetup{options=tip}% execute options set with \captionsetup[tip]{...}
    }
 {\endminipage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{code}[caption=Test]
Code test..
\end{code}

....Look, just because I don't be givin' no man a foot massage don't make it right for Marsellus....

\begin{tip}[caption=Test]
A tip!
\end{tip}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works almost as I want it to! Is it possible to get the "Tip 1" to be "Tip 1.1" instead? I tried use `numberbychapter=true` but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Which document class are you using? Chapter numbering only applies to book and report, not to article, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I just had to remove `\let\thelstlisting=\thetip` and the numbering looks as I want. Thanks a bunch!